# preg_match for post hex into existing routine

Tags: php, validation, preg-match

ADDED Full Script :

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$message = $_GET['message'];
//function to check for valid image formats
function uploadimage($dir){
if(!empty($_FILES)){
$url ='';  
$image = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG", "GIF");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($image["mime"] == "image/gif")
|| ($image["mime"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($image["mime"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($image["mime"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($image["mime"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($image["mime"] == "image/png"))
&& ($_FILES["image"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
    if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
    $path = $dir . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"],
    $dir . $_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $path = $dir . $_FILES["image"]["name"];
    }
    }
    }
else
    {
    $message = "Wrong format";
    }
}
return $path;
}

//declare form field and form field error variables
$themeErr = $authorErr = $subheadingErr = $bgcolourErr = "";
$theme = $author = $subheading = $bgcolour = "";

//form field validation
function validate_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
{
    $has_errors = false;
    if(empty($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"])){     
    $has_errors = true;
    $imageErr = "Missing image";
    }else{
    $dir = "uploads/";
    }

    if (empty($_POST["theme"])) {
    $has_errors = true;
    $themeErr = "Enter a theme name";
    }else{
    $theme = validate_input($_POST["theme"]);
    }

    if ($_POST["subheading"] === '') {
    $has_errors = false;
    $subheadingErr = "Enter subheading";
    } else {
    $subheading = validate_input($_POST["subheading"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["author"])) {
    $has_errors = true;
    $authorErr = "Enter author";
    }else {
    $author = validate_input($_POST["author"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["bgcolour"])) {
    $has_errors = true;
    $bgcolourErr = "Enter colour in hex";
} elseif (!preg_match('/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i',$_POST["bgcolor"])) {
    $has_errors = true;
    $bgcolourErr = "Enter # then six values";
} else {
    $bgcolor = validate_input($_POST["bgcolor"]);
}

//write data into database table
    if (!$has_errors)
    {
    $Link = mysql_connect($Host, $User, $Password);
    $user = $_SESSION['UserName'];
    $path = uploadimage($dir);

    $Query = "INSERT INTO tcgbackface VALUES ('','".mysql_escape_string($user)."','".mysql_escape_string($theme)."','".mysql_escape_string($subheading)."', '".mysql_escape_string($author)."','".mysql_escape_string($bgcolour)."')";

//pass id from form table into image table in order to link image to form
    if(mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query, $Link)) {
    $formid = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tcgbackface ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    $formid = mysql_fetch_array($formid);
    $Query = "INSERT INTO tcgbackfaceimages VALUES ('{$formid[0]}','".mysql_escape_string($user)."','{$path}')";
    } else {

    die("Query was: $Query. Error: ".mysql_error($Link));
    }

    if($sql = mysql_db_query ($DBName, $Query, $Link)) {
    $message = "Card Created";
    header("Location: backfacecreate.php?message=".urlencode($message));
    } else {
    die("Query was: $Query. Error: ".mysql_error($Link));
    }
    }
}
?>

<div><label class="labelcard">Theme</label><input id="theme" class="insetcard" name="theme" type="text" placeholder="theme" value="<?PHP print $theme ; ?>"/>
<p class="errorcard"><?php echo $themeErr;?></p></div>

<div><label class="labelcard">Sub Heading</label><input id="subheading" class="insetcard" name="subheading" type="text" placeholder="sub heading" value="<?PHP print $subheading ; ?>"/></div>

<div><label class="labelcard">Colour</label><input id="bgcolour" class="insetcard" name="bgcolour" type="text" placeholder="background colour" value="<?PHP print $bgcolour ; ?>"/><p class="errorcard"><?php echo $bgcolourErr;?></p></div>

<div><label class="labelcard">Author</label><input id="author" class="insetcard" name="author" type="text" placeholder="author" value="<?PHP print $author ; ?>"/><p class="errorcard"><?php echo $authorErr;?></p></div>
```

ADDED function code :

```
function validate_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}
```

I want to add validation specific to fields in my table. For example I want to ensure when a user inputs a hex colour they enter it in the correct format starting with a # and six alphanumerical characters - I know hex can be input with 3 values but I want to use six. In my validation I have variables for validation errors e.g. $bgcolourErr for background colour errors. The current routine checks for empty post values :

```
if (empty($_POST["bgcolour"])) {
    $has_errors = true;
    $bgcolourErr = "Enter colour in hex";
    } else {
    $bgcolour = validate_input($_POST["bgcolour"]);
    }
```

I've written preg_match routines for the fields in my database. e.g.

```
If (preg_match('/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i', $_POST['bgcolour'])) {
$bgcolour = validate_input($_POST["bgcolour"]);
}
```

But don't understand how to incorporate them into my existing routines. Sorry is this a newbie question but I don't understand how to structure the function in my code.

Comment: What does validate_input?

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but I'm unsure it is really what you're asking for

```
if (empty($_POST["bgcolour"])) {
    $has_errors = true;
    $bgcolourErr = "Enter colour in hex";
} elseif (!preg_match('/^#[a-f0-9]{6}$/i',$_POST["bgcolour"])) {
    $has_errors = true;
    $bgcolourErr = "Enter colour in hex, you entered something wrong";
} else {
    $bgcolourErr = "Valid entry";
    $bgcolour = validate_input($_POST["bgcolour"]);
}
```

Is `validate_input()`another function in your code ?

Comment: That didn't work. If there is no entry the first part executes i.e. enter colour in hex. Regardless of what I enter it always shows your message "Enter colour in hex, you entered something wrong".

Yes that's a function I use to strip characters from the post values. I've added the code.

Comment: I did assume you were initializing has_errors and Bgcolourerr before this code... Out of context it needs some assumption ;) Can you give more details ?

Comment: I've added the rest of the php and some of the HTML.

Comment: I've added a line to set the bgcolourErr to something else and not touching has_error. Seems your code store values in session between different posts... But I can't swear about it

Comment: A little off topic, but try to indent inside if..else blocks, it's easiest to read when properly formatted :)

Comment: Thanks it's working! This wasn't necessary $bgcolorErr = "Valid entry"; colour is spelt with a u in the UK, that's why the first code you posted didn't work.

Comment: Awww, sorry about that. It was to track down the error. I'll edit the answer